# Regex exclude numbers with point and 0 digit

Tags: regex

How can I modify my regex expression to achieve this conditions:

- 00.015 should not pass
- 001,07 should not pass
- +0.05 should pass
- 0000005 should pass
- .0000789 should pass

The logic is if there is more then one 0 before point it doesn't correct and check should return false.

My regex:

```
/^-?\d*[\.\,]?\d+$/)
```

Comment: `/^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?[.,]?\d+$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead asserting not 2 times a zero and optional digits till you encounter a `,` or `.`

```
^(?!00\d*[.,])[+-]?\d*[.,]?\d+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!00\d*[.,])` Negative lookahead, assert not `00` followed by optional digits and `.` or `,`
- `[+-]?` Match optional `+` or `-`
- `\d*[.,]?\d+` Match optional digits, optional `.` or `,` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LIb5YC/1)